# React hot reload not working for 2 files within my entire project on VS Code

Tags: reactjs

I'm using VS Code to run a react project. Suddenly 2 files within the project are no longer triggering the hot reload functionality using the cmd + s short cut key.

Has someone experienced something similar to this in the past?

I have already tried restarting the react app, VS Code, and Mac M2 laptop to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout the file name and where the file is used. Sometimes we just no use the right file name that's why hot reload is not working.

You can try to remove `node_modules` and reinstall by writing `npm install`

Comment: Thanks file name was part of the issue, silly me

Answer (score 0):

So sorry I might have jumped too soon and posted this issue.

I've found the solution, the issue was that I was pulling 2 files that were never used in the project. I guess I've learned something new, if a file is never used in the react app it will not trigger a hot reload.

Sorry for the nuance.